# Go cd configuration issue

Tags: windows, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, go-cd

I've been having an issue trying to add github materials from a private repo on a Windows server.

I've seen lots of people suggesting how to add the ssh keys and where but on unix based systems. Haven't found anything related to Windows Servers.

I'm using Go latest release and have installed Go Server & Agent on a Windows Server 2008 with git installed.

I can connect to the private repo using Git Bash.

Whenever I try to add the materials it keeps saying Checking Connection and looks like it stays there forever.

If I use basic auth it works but I would like to make it work without exposing my password in the URL.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you run Go under the default local system account, you can follow the suggestions from http://opensourcetester.co.uk/2013/06/28/jenkins-windows-ssh/ to setup the ssh keys for local system account.

If you run Go Server under a domain account (and not the default Local System account), check if you have uploaded your ssh keys to %USERPROFILE%/.ssh/ folder on the server machine, %USERPROFILE% being HOME folder for the domain user. Once you set that up, Go server would be able to pick the required keys. The same holds good for the agent machines. Just so you know, Go would not invoke Git-bash internally to run the git commands, so any setup on bash will not take effect when running git from within Go.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a windows machine to host GoCD server and agents , it does not run under a normal user account, it runs under the “Local System Account”

So even you can access your git repo from git bash (logged in as the current user),GOCD cannot access the same.

So you need to add the SSH keys for the Local System Account from your your current user.

1.First find the home directory for the Local System Account(It will not reside under C:/Users )

2.Use any remote administration tool to find the home directory- If you go with http://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip

a)unzip and run command-line as administrator

b)PsExec.exe -i -s cmd.exe -start the tool )

c)run echo %userprofile% to get the home directory (eg:C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile)

3.Now you can either copy the SSH key files from current user or create a new one using ssh commands.

Try checking Connection after creating/copying the SSH keys, it will show Connection OK!